# Fit elements into box

Tags: algorithm, bounds, tag-cloud, texturepacker

I want to achieve the effect shown in the images attached. Given certain items, fit them into a shape (box or something else), with the option to resize the items or not.

I know there has to be some **algorithm** related, but I don't know where to start looking.

Any **keyword**, **wikipedia** article, or **pdf** will be welcome.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe try this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem just a thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as [NKamrath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/873461/nkamrath) pointed out, was **Bin packing problem**, but more commonly refered to **Texture Packing**. Here are the resources I gathered:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem
- http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/lightmaps/default.html
- http://www.gamedev.net/topic/392413-rectangle-packing/
- http://clb.demon.fi/projects/rectangle-bin-packing
- http://clb.demon.fi/projects/more-rectangle-bin-packing
- http://clb.demon.fi/files/RectangleBinPack.pdf